# Website Entry Script

Tags: php, html, cookies

I want users to view an ad before they visit my website. The ad would be a page that says Please wait 5 seconds to continue and then my advertisments below.

My question is how can I force the user to view it and how can I make a limit on how many times it is shown.

Comment: So a separate page, not a popup?

Comment: Use a cookie to count the number of times they've been to your page. If it's lower than the limit, redirect them to the ad page.

Comment: @BecsCarter Yes Exactly

Comment: Sounds like a good way to drive visitors away from your site...

Comment: Yes, I thought about that @Barmar , but they would just use cookie spoofing.

Comment: @MikeW Thats why i only want to do it at a limit of 1 time every 4 hours and I have over 8k active users. Im sure I would not mind if i drop 100 because they want to be selfish and inconsiderate.

Comment: If you're really worried about that, use a PHP session variable.

Comment: Most sites with an entry ad also have a "Click here to go directly" link.

Comment: Since when is it "selfish and inconsiderate" to choose not to buy a product that somebody is selling?  You may want to consider revising your opinion of customers.

Comment: @david I am providing them with a free service as I pay the bills for it. Its either I place 1 entire ad every 24 hours or I charge them to use the site.

Comment: @SimplePi: I'll let the irony slowly sink in that you're asking for programming help on... a free service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Adf.ly Visitor script. It pays in paypal. I once tried something like this myself but it was easily spoofed.

Comment: Not realy what im looking for but it will work